# ssh/scp config file with proxycommand still asks for password

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, remote

My setup is like this:

```
[local machine] --> [university network] --> [local machine in university network]
   [machine1]   -->       [machine2]     -->              [machine3]
```

I have setup passwordless access with `ssh-keygen`. When I'm on *machine1*, I can type `ssh user2@machine2` and I am promptly connected. I can move on from there to type `ssh user3@machine3` and [I'm in](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/85378482.jpg).

I now want to be able to type `ssh machine3` on *machine1* and directly connect the the third machine. I  wrote the following .ssh/config file:

```
Host machine3
    Hostname machine3
    ProxyCommand ssh user2@machine2 -W %h:%p
    User user3
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

However, now I am always prompted for the password for *user3*. If I type it in, I'm connected, so the tunneling works. How can I skip typing in the password for user3?

Machine1 is Windows10 Pro (I'm using the ssh command in the power-shell).
Machine2 runs Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Machine3 runs Linux Mint 20.3 Una

Comment: Hint: your setup is not equivalent to connecting from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3 (like in the manual method). It's connecting from 1 to 2 and from 1 to 3. Credentials for 3 must therefore come from 1. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski so I need to copy my public key from machine1 to machine3?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not going to actually test this and write an answer. If you succeed, please you write an answer. There is no need to mention my input in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in the comments, I mistakenly assumed, that I would connect with a "stop" on machine2. However, that's not the case. The solution is to copy the ssh public key both to machine2 and machine3 from machine1.